# How to instantiate a com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar object given an oAuth token?

Tags: android, oauth, google-calendar-api

I have gotten oAuth Tokens for each calendar that is being used in my android app using this code

```
private HashMap<String, String> getAuthrizedCalendarsOnPhone() {
    HashMap<String, String> authorized_calendars = new HashMap<String, String>();

    AccountManager acctmgr = AccountManager.get(app_context);
    Account[] accounts = acctmgr.getAccountsByType("com.google");

    for (Account account : accounts) {
        String auth_token_type = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";
        AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> amf = acctmgr.getAuthToken(account, auth_token_type, null, this, null, null);

        String authToken;
        try {
            Bundle authTokenBundle = amf.getResult();
            authToken = authTokenBundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            authToken = "";
        }
        authorized_calendars.put(account.name, authToken);
    }

    return authorized_calendars;
}
```

Now how do I instantiate a `com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar` object using that oAuth Token so I can access the calendar api on behalf of that user?

i.e. so I can do something like this

```
private HashMap<String, HCEvent> getCalendarEvents(String calendar_name) {
    HashMap<String, HCEvent> return_map = new HashMap<String, HCEvent>();
    com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar service = null; //create a Calendar object using the oauth token for associated with calendar_name
    com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events events = service.events().list(calendar_name).setPageToken(pageToken).execute();

    /*
     * do something with the events
     */

    return return_map;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After looking at some of the Google Calendar API's and examples it looks like the best way to assign a token to the Calendar is when initializing it. This takes some setup, take a look at this link:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate

My apologies if you have already been through it, but it looks like you may be able to make a few adjustments to that example.

Right before the Calendar is initialized, this snipped of code is executed:

```
    GoogleAccessProtectedResource accessProtectedResource = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(
    response.accessToken, httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret,
    response.refreshToken);
```

which in turn is used as part of the Calendars initialization.

Looking at the documentation for GoogleAccessProtectedResource it looks like there exists a constructor which just takes in an access token.

http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.4.1-beta/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/draft10/GoogleAccessProtectedResource.html#GoogleAccessProtectedResource(java.lang.String)

You can use the tokens that you have already requested in your method before, then with a couple other objects described in the google calendar instantiate link above, you should be able to properly instantiate the calendar with the given access token.

Hope this helps,

**EDIT**

It looks like the GoogleAccessProtectedResource is actually going to be deprecated, or already is.

The javadoc states:

"Deprecated. (scheduled to be removed in 1.8) Use GoogleCredential"

http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.7.0-beta/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/draft10/GoogleAccessProtectedResource.html

So it looks like what you will need is GoogleCredential to replace GoogleAccessProtectedResource. I found that you can setup a credential with an access token like so:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
```

Then you can create the new calendar by doing this:

```
Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
            credential).build();
```

Where the httpTransport and jsonFactory would be similar to what the other example had.

Good Luck!

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, but where do I download the jar that has `GoogleAccessProtectedResource`? It doesn't seem to be included in the Google Calendar API java client.

Comment: It also seems like that method is deprecated, are you sure it's ok to use?

Comment: That's not quite working, although I think it's close. I'm getting a 401 error for invalid credentials, any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: hmm 401 is typically an unauthorized code, meaning that the token may be expired. I would verify that you are using the correct API key and that everything is setup properly. I don't have a great deal of time to investigate the issue to much further today, but this link may be helpful. https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials